# Appcompat v7 Android 5.0 ActionBarActivity TextView Not Visible

Tags: eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I've attempting to upgrade my Android project to compile with Android 5.0.  I was using the appcompat-v7 library successfully before this.  Now using ActionBarActivity and Theme.AppCompat  causes the views in my fragment layout not to render or not to be visible.  If I change it back to Activity and remove the appcompat theme, the views are visible again.  Can anyone point out the configuration that I'm doing wrong?  My Eclipse project is compiling with Android 5.0, Private Libraries of android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar.  Under Android dependencies is android-support-v7-appcompat.jar.

And I have the following code:

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE something>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.ctest"
    android:versionCode="33"
    android:versionName="1.4.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="My App" 
        android:allowBackup="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE something>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Nothing here"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In MyActivity.java:

```
package com.mycompany.ctest;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private FragmentManager mFM;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mFM = getFragmentManager();
        mFM.beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, new MyFragment(),"frag")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

And in MyFragment.java:

```
package com.mycompany.ctest;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,group,false);
    }
}
```

EDIT:  LogCat shows 
12-13 10:10:09.709: E/ResourceType(1013): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479

Although I think that must be irrelevant because if I add an Activity layout with a static fragment loaded instead of using the Fragment Manager, my view becomes visible.  And I still get the Style contains key with bad entry message.

Answer (score 1):

I finally added an activity layout with a blank frame layout with id.

activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Then used that id when adding fragments to the activity with .add or .replace instead of using android.R.id.content.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container,new MyFragment(), "frag")
                .commit();
```

I still don't know why that works and why android.R.id.content was not working.

Comment: Mary, if you answered your own question, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing from support library instead of just "import android.app.Fragment;" ...hope this might help

```
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: I changed to v4 Fragment in MyFragment and v4 FragmentManager in MyActivity.  Also, I changed to getSupportFragmentManager.  Still no luck